# GitHub Contribution Histograms

Tags: git, github, histogram

I'm trying to understand the GitHub contributions data, and the way they display it. I created a silly 2-step process to "draw" on the contributions [*(which can be found here)*](http://gitcanvas.herokuapp.com).

I've just realized the "weight" for each day is relative to the rest of the year, rather than fixed. Thus, I'd like to do two additional functions.

## Flatten

Taking your public contribution history and creating commits as needed so that there's the same amount every day in the year. For this to work I'd need to:

- AJAX request the data from my own server *(since they don't allow XSS)*
- From there, request `https://github.com/users/%s/contributions_calendar_data` [(example)](https://github.com/users/bevacqua/contributions_calendar_data)
- Create enough commits each day to equal the *highest public activity* in the year

## Pick a Color

On top of the flattening, I'd like to provide the functionality to pick a color (one of the shades of green GitHub paints your daily activity with). This is where I have *no idea what to do*.

I won't be providing the functionality without "flattening" the commit activity first, since that seems even more daunting. But, my questions are:

- Given a commit activity history where every single day has **T** commits, *how many commits* are needed **to achieve** each hue "tier"?
- How do these values change when introducing new commits?

For example, say I flatten the commit history to 85 commits per day, how many commits will each color require? Will these be different if I include more levels?

If the "base level" is 400, rather than 85, how will that affect the commit history?

For reference, [this is the repo](https://github.com/bevacqua/gitcanvas) I'm doing the experimenting on. It's basically a web interface that let's you "draw", and a CLI that takes the JSON output of the UI and generates a bunch of empty commits for you.

Needless to say I don't know much about statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Great questions!

> AJAX request the data from my own server (since they don't allow XSS)

To get the public contributions, you can use [`ghcal`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/ghcal) like below:

```
var GhCal = require("ghcal");

GhCal("bevacqua", function (err, data) {
    console.log(err || data);
});
```

This will give you in the callback an output like this:

```
[..., ["2015-04-26", 22], ...]
```

> Given a commit activity history where every single day has **T** commits, how many commits are needed to achieve each hue "tier"?

From my tests, if every single day has the same number of commits (`T`), then to make one day darker, you just need to add one more commit (that would mean `T + 1` on that day).

While creating [`git-stats`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats), I had the same questions. The exact rule how this works is not open. I emailed GitHub asking for their algorithm and they replied:

> We can't share how exactly the colors are computed (and we tweak that from time to time), but it's based on mapping the contribution count for a specific day to a color based on the distribution of contribution counts for the whole year (each range is assigned a specific color).

So, in short, as you noticed, there are five levels and the data is normalized to have different levels depending of how many commits are done per day, and the algorithm behind this is changed *from time to time*.

> For example, say I flatten the commit history to 85 commits per day, how many commits will each color require?

From my tests, only one more.

> Will these be different if I include more levels?

Yes, but honestly, you should try it. `:D`

> If the "base level" is 400, rather than 85, how will that affect the commit history?

I'm almost sure that in this case, the difference will be notable only when you want to have more than one level. If you have 400 for all days, except one where you have 401, I guess that day will be darker than the others.

Probably it's better to let the user decide how many commits (s)he wants to create a day. `:)`

[`github-contributions`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-contributions) is a project created by me which does related things (draws/create texts on the contributions calendar).